# Como sumar valores en una tabla sin que se duplique el valor

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a la base de datos sin poder obtener los datos esperados, quiero obtener las ganancias y los descuentos por meses de las ventas.

tabla venta

```
CREATE TABLE `tblventas` (
  `idVenta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ventaNumero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ventaTotal` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ventaDcto` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ventaMedioPago` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ventaFecha` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ventaClienteId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ventaEstado` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ventaUsuario` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `tblventas` (`idVenta`, `ventaNumero`, `ventaTotal`, `ventaDcto`, `ventaMedioPago`, `ventaFecha`, `ventaClienteId`, `ventaEstado`, `ventaUsuario`) VALUES
(1, 1, '7000', 0.00, 1, '2023-08-01 00:00:00', 2, 3, 1),
(2, 2, '2500', 200.00, 1, '2023-08-02 13:46:47', 2, 3, 1),
(3, 3, '7000', 0.00, 1, '2023-08-10 17:07:24', 2, 3, 1),
(4, 4, '41500', 500.00, 2, '2023-08-16 00:00:00', 1, 3, 1),
(5, 5, '41500', 0.00, 1, '2023-08-17 17:04:14', 2, 3, 1),
(6, 6, '9500', 500.00, 1, '2023-06-01 00:00:00', 2, 3, 1),
(7, 7, '12500', 0.00, 1, '2023-08-22 17:54:22', 2, 3, 1);
```

tabla detalledeventa

```
CREATE TABLE `tbldetalleventas` (
  `idDetalleVenta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detv_VentaNumero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detv_Cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detv_PrecioVenta` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `detv_PrecioCompra` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `detv_ProductoId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `tbldetalleventas` (`idDetalleVenta`, `detv_VentaNumero`, `detv_Cantidad`, `detv_PrecioVenta`, `detv_PrecioCompra`, `detv_ProductoId`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 7000.00, 4000.00, 1),
(2, 2, 1, 2500.00, 2000.00, 2),
(3, 3, 1, 7000.00, 5000.00, 1),
(4, 4, 2, 7000.00, 5000.00, 1),
(5, 4, 1, 2500.00, 2000.00, 2),
(6, 4, 5, 5000.00, 3000.00, 3),
(7, 5, 2, 7000.00, 5000.00, 1),
(8, 5, 1, 2500.00, 2000.00, 2),
(9, 5, 5, 5000.00, 3000.00, 3),
(10, 6, 1, 7000.00, 5000.00, 1),
(11, 6, 1, 2500.00, 2000.00, 2),
(12, 7, 1, 5000.00, 4000.00, 1),
(13, 7, 1, 2500.00, 2000.00, 2),
(14, 7, 1, 5000.00, 3000.00, 3);
```

realizo esta consulta que me trae el total bien pero el Dcto me lo esta duplicando

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(ventaFecha) AS Mes, YEAR(ventaFecha) as Ano, COALESCE(SUM((detv_PrecioVenta - detv_PrecioCompra)* detv_Cantidad),0) AS Total,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Vta.ventaDcto),0) FROM tblventas Vta) AS Dcto
    FROM tblventas
    LEFT JOIN tbldetalleventas ON detv_VentaNumero = ventaNumero WHERE ventaEstado=3
    GROUP BY Mes ORDER BY MONTH(ventaFecha) ASC
```

este es el resultado de la consulta

[image: imagen del resultado de la consulta]

en la columna Dcto debería ser 500 para junio y 700 para agosto

también intente de esta manera

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(ventaFecha) AS Mes, YEAR(ventaFecha) as Ano, COALESCE(SUM((detv_PrecioVenta - detv_PrecioCompra)* detv_Cantidad),0) AS Total, COALESCE(SUM(ventaDcto),0) AS Dcto FROM tblventas LEFT JOIN tbldetalleventas ON detv_VentaNumero = ventaNumero WHERE ventaEstado=3 GROUP BY Mes ORDER BY MONTH(ventaFecha) ASC
```

y el No dio el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

resultado esperado

```
Mes     Ano   Total     Dcto
June    2023  2500.00   500.00
August  2023  38000.00  700.00
```

como puedo obtener este resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La subconsulta no tiene ningún condicional, y al no tener control sobre los datos de la columna, devuelve la suma de todos. Por eso da `1200` en todos los casos.

Para arreglarlo, poner un `WHERE` dentro de la subconsulta con el criterio de agrupamiento:

```sql
SELECT MONTHNAME(ventaFecha) AS Mes, YEAR(ventaFecha) as Ano, 
COALESCE(SUM((detv_PrecioVenta - detv_PrecioCompra)* detv_Cantidad), 0) AS Total,
(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Vta.ventaDcto), 0) 
    FROM tblventas Vta
    WHERE MONTH(Vta.ventaFecha) = MONTH(tblventas.ventaFecha) -- Línea agregada
) AS Dcto
FROM tblventas
LEFT JOIN tbldetalleventas ON detv_VentaNumero = ventaNumero 
WHERE ventaEstado=3
GROUP BY Mes 
ORDER BY MONTH(ventaFecha) ASC
```

Aunque también podría ser `WHERE MONTHNAME(Vta.ventaFecha) = Mes`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y la explicación es justo lo que necesitaba